# DCT based Video Encoding Process

Tags: c++, video-encoding, huffman-code, dct, run-length-encoding

I am having some issues that I am hoping you will be able to clarify. I have self taught myself a video encoding process similar to Mpeg2. The process is as follows:

1. Split an RGBA image into 4 separate channel data memory blocks. so an array of all R values, a separate array of G values etc.
2. take the array and grab a block of 8x8 pixel data, to transform it using the Discrete Cosine Transform (DCT).
3. Quantize this 8x8 block using a pre-calculated quantization matrix.
4. Zigzag encode the output of the quantization step. So I should get a trail of consecutive numbers.
5. Run Length Encode (RLE) the output from the zigzag algorithm.
6. Huffman Code the data after the RLE stage. Using substitution of values from a pre-computed huffman table.
7. Go back to step 2 and repeat until all the channels data has been encoded
8. Go back to step 2 and repeat for each channel

First question is do I need to convert the RGBA values to YUV+A (YCbCr+A) values for the process to work or can it continue using RGBA? I ask as the RGBA->YUVA conversion is a heavy workload that I would like to avoid if possible.

Next question. I am wondering should the RLE store runs for just 0's or can that be extended to all the values in the array? See examples below:

```
 440000000111 == [2,4][7,0][3,1]   // RLE for all values
 or
 440000000111 == 44[7,0]111        // RLE for 0's only
```

The final question is what would a single symbol be in regard to the huffman stage? would a symbol to be replaced be a value like 2 or 4, or would a symbol be the Run-level pair [2,4] for example.

Thanks for taking the time to read and help me out here. I have read many papers and watched many youtube videos, which have aided my understanding of the individual algorithms but not how they all link to together to form the encoding process in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(this seems more like JPEG than MPEG-2 - video formats are more about compressing differences between frames, rather than just image compression)

If you work in RGB rather than YUV, you're probably not going to get the same compression ratio and/or quality, but you can do that if you want. Colour-space conversion is hardly a heavy workload compared to the rest of the algorithm.

Typically in this sort of application you RLE the zeros, because that's the element that you get a lot of repetitions of (and hopefully also a good number at the end of each block which can be replaced with a single marker value), whereas other coefficients are not so repetitive but if you expect repetitions of other values, I guess YMMV.

And yes, you can encode the RLE pairs as single symbols in the huffman encoding.

Comment: Thanks very much for the quick and thorough response. 1) Yes, I suppose you can say its more like JPEG than MPEG-2 as I am only interested in encoding a series of I-frames rather than P/B-frames. 2) I did some profiling and the YUV converter I was using (fully optimised SIMD MMX assembly) was the slowest function on my CPU. 3) Thanks for clearing the RLE/Huffman stage up for me. Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1) Yes you'll want to convert to YUV... to achieve higher compression ratios, you need to take advantage of the human eye's ability to "overlook" significant loss in color.  Typically, you'll keep your Y plane the same resolution (presumably the A plane as well), but downsample the U and V planes by 2x2.  E.g. if you're doing 640x480, the Y is 640x480 and the U and V planes are 320x240.  Also, you might choose different quantization for the U/V planes.  The cost for this conversion is small compared to DCT or DFT.

2) You don't have to RLE it, you could just Huffman Code it directly.

Comment: I am trying to replace an encoder in use now, that I don't have the source code for. I know it's MPEG-2 based. I started out using the wavelet based Schroedinger codec [link](http://diracvideo.org/). I didn't want patent issues. I had it working with an alpha channel in VS2005. I implemented an RGBA->YUV+A converter for this encoder attempt. The YUV was of form YUV420. Unfortunately I could not get this encoder to be as performant as the original both in terms of memory consumption and speed. so I left it for the older MPEG-2 system and RGBA. Hope that explains where my thinking lies.

Comment: As an aside, have you looked into Google's WebM/libvpx/VP8 codec?  It's a great video codec (arguably near mpeg4 quality), multiple platforms, with source.  You can set it to do all I/Key frames if you want (basically WebP)...

Comment: I have had a look at WebM Mark. It does appear to be the next 'big thing' so far as video encoders go. As with Schroedinger my understanding is: it is wavelet based and designed for streaming large (HD) files. So I imagine I will find I have similar issues with WebM as I have found with Schroedinger. It should be noted that I spent a silly amount of time fixing Schroedinger to run through VS2005 and adding alpha channel support into it. I don't have the time to go through the same trouble with WebM.