# Should I Huffman Encode a single frame, a colour channel of that frame or an 8x8 macroblock?

Tags: encode, huffman-code, dct

Further to my question a couple of days ago about the  [DCT based Video Encoding Process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14398229/dct-based-video-encoding-process)

I have DCT, quantization, zigzag and RLE steps that seem to be outputting sensible values so I now need to know should I run the Huffman Encode over the entire frame, a colour channel of that frame or at the 8x8 macroblock level?

Comment: Use a range coder if you can. They always provide better results than a huffman coder.

Comment: Why don't you take a look at what existing codecs (e.g. JPEG) do?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I haven't heard of a range coder before I shall look it up. I will have to use huffman for this project though as I have to emulate the encoding/decoding process used by some in house software that uses huffman coding.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I have done this and its got me to this point. Very hard to figure out the scope of the huffman step though. i.e. should I huff the whole frames run-level values or just one channel or just one 8x8 block at a time.

Comment: @FUZxxl From what I have read Range Coding is a subset of arithmetic coding? As I mentioned the huffman system I am using employs look up tables which are super fast which is more important in my usage scenario than whether the end result is pixel perfect. Thanks for the good suggestion though much appreciated.

Comment: Huffman ans range coding both are pretty fast and roughly comparable. Range coding tends to be cpu bound (lots of divisions) while Huffman is more memory bound. Range coding is used in JPEG 2000 and yields 25% better compression on average (?). There is a speed difference but it is rather tiny.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's tricky to give a definitive answer, because really it depends on your data, and how complex you want your decoder to be.

You probably don't want to use a single huffman encoding for all the different types of data you have in your stream, as the symbols used are different, and appear in different frequencies (i.e. AC components are not the same as DC components, and if you've used a non-RGB colour space, luminance is not the same as chroma). The JPEG method is to use different tables for different items of data, but the data is interleaved in the stream (so it's still parsed sequentially). These tables are not necessarily calculated dynamically for the data, but instead often just use default values.

Beyond that observation, I don't think how you break up or interleave the data will make much difference.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I already have the set of huffman lookup tables ready to use, from the system I am trying to emulate. My problem is knowing over what range to apply them i.e. generate huff codes based on the whole frames run-level pairs or just a single channel or generate the codes for the DCT scope which is the 8x8 macroblock level. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: I don't think it matters. At least, not in the sense of affecting the size of the output - not unless you're introducting extra padding for some reason, and I can't think why you'd want to do that unless you're adding sync points for error recovery or something. Otherwise it's just a matter of what order you *want* your data in.

Comment: No I'm not introducing padding or extra data. I generate my run-level pairs at the macroblock level currently so for subsequent 8x8 blocks I might have [4,1],[10,45],[12,0],... in block 1 and in block 2: [6,1],[5,13],[18,0],... so knowing the range to apply the huffman too would have an affect on the probabilities I am generating. Note how combining the two blocks run-level pairs gives differing probabilities [4+6/55,1],[10/55,45],[5/55,13],[30/55,0],...

Comment: You said you *had* tables. If you're generating them, I can't imagine that doing so on a per-block basis would be efficient, due to the need to actually store the huffman table in some fashion, unless you run some kind of adaptive scheme, and unless each block had radically different frequencies of symbol, which would indicate to me that your compression is broken in the first place, as making the data compressible was the aim of the quantization.

Comment: Yes I do already have tables sorry if I have confused this point. Perhaps I should have worded my question as "I don't know how my huffman tables were generated, so how do I utilise these tables with my run-level pairs?" I think the answer I'm looking for is as you say "I don't think it matters."

Comment: Well the simple answer is that you should use those tables to encode data which has very similar frequencies to those it was generated for. Anything else is unlikely to give good results. Beyond that, you can structure the data however you like.